# Gradient Descent diverges, learning rate too high

Tags: python-3.x, gradient-descent

There is a piece of code below, which does GD step by step but theta is diverging. What could be wrong?

```
X = arange(100)
Y = 50 + 4*X + uniform(-20, 20, X.shape)

theta = array([0,0])
alpha = 0.001
# one step of GD
theta0 = theta[0] - alpha * sum( theta[0]+theta[1]*x-y    for x,y in zip(X,Y))/len(X)
theta1 = theta[1] - alpha * sum((theta[0]+theta[1]*x-y)*x for x,y in zip(X,Y))/len(X)
theta = [theta0, theta1]
```

Comment: Does it diverge if you perform 10 steps rather than just one?

Comment: Yeah, every step goes more and more the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learning rate was too high.

```
alpha = 0.0001
```